# GTK+ 3: Restore TreeViewColumn widths without making them behave as if manually sized

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtktreeview

I have a `TreeView` whose columns are all expandable with fixed-mode sizing. I would like to restore the widths of the columns when the user restarts the app. It seems that calling `set_fixed_size` is the way to do this, but:

- If I set only the widths of the columns that the user resized, then the actual column widths end up different from what they were before.
- If instead I set all column widths explicitly, then all columns behave as though they had been resized by the user, which is not ideal.

Is there a way to restore the column widths that gets around these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `expand` interferes with `fixed_width`. In my case, the solution was to set `fixed_width` and `expand=false` on columns that the user resized, and `expand=true` on the others.